# Editing remotely the PHP files on a Centos server

Tags: windows-7, centos6, ubuntu-12.04

I have a intranet web server (Centos 6, Apache, PHP) to which I would like to give access to a developer. He will connect by remote desktop from Windows 7 to Ubuntu 12.4 and from here by SSH to `/var/www/html` folder where it has to create and edit the files.

This solution was chosen because:
- I could not make a remote desktop connection from  Windows to Centos
- The web developer need some editor for PHP files and is not allowed to install software on Windows 7 machine
- it is more a  test solution ( we are all learning to use Linux).

1. When the developer is connected from Ubuntu to Centos by SSH (SFTP) he could save the changes only if on Centos the account used to connect has ownership to that folder. Can you please tell how can I give all required rights. I tried different solutions found on Internet but without to much success.
2. Are there other way to connect to Centos server?

Answer (score 0):

1) I don't understand.  Why can't you grant the developer's account permissions to the files and/or folders he's editing?

2) There are any number of other ways.

My advice, in order of preference would be to install an SSH client on the developer's Windows 7 machine ([PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html)), and have him connect directly or to install a remote desktop daemon on the CentOS machine ([such as xrdp](http://www.xrdp.org/)).  You could also use VNC or any other number of other technologies, but I don't see any reason they'd be preferable to either SSH or RDP in this situation.